# How to use the OTSU Threshold in opencv?

Tags: opencv, threshold

I was using a fixed threshold but turns out that it's not so good for me. Then, someone told me about the otsu threshold. How can I use it in my code?
I read about it and I don't understand very well. Could someone explain to me how to use it in OpenCV the otsu threshold?

Here is my code now:

```c
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

    using namespace cv;

    int main ( int argc, char **argv )
    {
       Mat im_gray = imread("img3.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

       Mat im_rgb  = imread("img3.jpg");
       cvtColor(im_rgb,im_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);

       Mat img_bw = im_gray > 115;

       imwrite("img_bw3.jpg", img_bw);

       return 0;
    }
```

With this I have to change the threshold to any image that I want to convert to binary. I found this:

```
    cvThreshold(scr, dst, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
```

Is that right?
I don't understand very well and because of that, didn't know how I could adapt to my code.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**Following line makes otsu thresholding operation:**

```
cv::threshold(im_gray, img_bw, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
```

- `im_gray` is a source 8-bit image,
- `img_bw` is a result,
- 0 means threshold level which actually is omitted because we used CV_THRESH_OTSU flag,
- 255 is a value that is going to be assigned to respectively pixels in the result (namely, to all pixels which value in the source is greater then computed threshold level)
- `CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU` is a required flag to perform Otsu thresholding. Because in fact we would like to perform binary thresholding, so we use `CV_THRESH_BINARY` (you can use any of 5 flags opencv provides) combined with `CV_THRESH_OTSU`

Link to documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold

Answer (score 16):

In python it is simple

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img.jpg',0)  #pass 0 to convert into gray level 
ret,thr = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('win1', thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score -1):

In Android is one line.

```
Imgproc.threshold(matGrayIn, matOtsuOut, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU | Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
```